# SQL Server Availability Group Automatic Failover Not Working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, high-availability

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application using Entity Framework to connect a SQL Server 2012 configured with high availability. It is configured to automatically fail over to a secondary server and this works well when trying to connect with SQL Server Management Studio. I could confirm this, and read or write data to database.

Somehow this doesn't happen from the application and I got the following error:

> The target database ('DbName') is in an availability group and is currently accessible for connections when the application intent is set to read only. For more information about application intent, see SQL Server Books Online.

This is the connection string that I am using:

```
<add name="DataModel" 
     connectionString="Data Source=DBCL01;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=user; Password=password;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Anyone knows how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your application is not being directed to the primary (writable) server, but is redirected to read-only secondary replica.

I had a similar problem, my problem was that the connection string was lacking `ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite` and that the availability listener wasn't being resolved good by the DNS.

Also check this [AlwaysOn Availability Groups Connectivity Cheat Sheet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2012/09/13/alwayson-connectivity-cheat-sheet.aspx) since bad setting of connectivity options for availability group can be a cause for connectivity errors and denial for connection to primary server.